# Multibinding expression always showing DependencyProperty.UnsetValue in it's multiconverter

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, multibinding

```
<ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu>
     <MenuItem IsCheckable="False" x:Name="MnuSendToFolder" Header="{Binding Path=SendToFolder, 
          Source={StaticResource LRWpf}}"   Command="{Binding SendToFolderCommand}" >
       <MenuItem.IsEnabled>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource VisibilityConverter}">
               <Binding ElementName="QuantChartWindow" Path="DataContext.IsSurveyModeOn" />
               <Binding ElementName="QuantChartWindow" Path="DataContext.CommonProgressVisibility" />
          </MultiBinding> 
        </MenuItem.IsEnabled>
     </MenuItem>
   </ContextMenu>
</ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

Here, QuantChartWindow is the name of the main UserControl whose data context is set as the viewmodel of this control.
IsSurveyModeOn and CommonProgressVisibility are public properties of the viewmodel.
In Convert function of the multiconverter, both the values comes always as UnsetValue.

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(values!=null && values.Length==2)
        {
            Visibility visvalue = (Visibility)values[1];
            bool isSurveyMode = (bool)values[0];
            if (visvalue == Visibility.Hidden || visvalue == Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                if(!isSurveyMode)
                    return true;
            }    
            else
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Adding the QuantChartWindow declaration part:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UI.SpectrumView.Views.QuantChartView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
          xmlns:c1="http://schemas.componentone.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UI.SpectrumView.Views"
          xmlns:spccon="clr-namespace:UI.SpectrumView.Converter"
         xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:UI.Converter;assembly=Comp.UI"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         **x:Name="QuantChartWindow"**
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Background="{DynamicResource DefaultColor}">
```

Code-Behind file

```
 public partial class QuantChartView : UserControl, IView
{
    QuantChartViewModel _viewModel;
    public QuantChartView(QuantChartViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = vm;
        _viewModel = vm;
        vm.Chart1 = Chart1;
        vm.Chart2 = Chart2;
        vm.GridChart2 = GridChart2;
        vm.View = this;

    }
```

}

View Model class QuantChartViewModel.cs

```
 public class QuantChartViewModel : DockWindowViewModel
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private ICommonService _common;
   public QuantChartViewModel(IUnityContainer container, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, ICommonService common)
    {
       this._container = container;
        this.QuantViewModel = container.Resolve<QuantViewModel>();
        _common = common;
    }
     private bool _isSurveyModeEnabled =false;
     public bool IsSurveyModeOn
     {
       get
        {
            return QuantViewModel.IsEDSSurveyMode;
        }
     }
    private Visibility _commonProgressVisibility;
     public bool CommonProgressVisibility
     {
       get
        {
            return _common.CommonProgressVisibility;
        }
     }

}
```

Full xaml code:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="UI.SpectrumView.Views.QuantChartView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
             compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
              xmlns:c1="http://schemas.componentone.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UI.SpectrumView.Views"
              xmlns:spccon="clr-namespace:UI.SpectrumView.Converter"
             xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:UI.Converter;assembly=Comp.UI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="QuantChartWindow"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Background=" 
             {DynamicResource DefaultColor}">
  <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TabControl Name="TabControl1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Background="{DynamicResource DefaultColor}" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
               SelectedIndex="{Binding TabSelectedIndex}">
            <TabItem Header="{Binding Path=tbGraph,  Source={StaticResource 
               LRWpf}}" Controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize="16" 
                 x:Name="tabControlItem" >

                <StackPanel Name="ChartPanel">

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ListView MinHeight="30" x:Name="lstChartMode" 
                           Width="120" >
                            <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource 
                                DefaultIconColor}" Height="25" Width="25"  
                                   Margin="5,0,0,0" >
                            </Rectangle>

                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <c1:C1Chart Name="Chart1" ChartType="{Binding 
                       SelectedChartType}" Palette="Module"  Margin="0,10,0,0">
                        <ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                 <MenuItem IsCheckable="False" 
                                       x:Name="MnuSendToFolder" Header=" 
                                       {Binding Path=SendToFolder, Source= 
                                       {StaticResource LRWpf}}" Command=" 
                                       {Binding SendToFolderCommand}">
                                     <MenuItem.IsEnabled>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter=" 
                                           {StaticResource 
                                                 VisibilityConverter}">
                                            <Binding 
                                              ElementName="QuantChartWindow" 
                                          Path="DataContext.IsSurveyModeOn"/>
                                            <Binding 
                                              ElementName="QuantChartWindow" 
                                Path="DataContext.CommonProgressVisibility"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                       </MenuItem.IsEnabled>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </ContextMenu>
                        </ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </c1:C1Chart>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
   </UserControl>
```

Comment: It is difficult to help, when your are not showing the code for your multibinding converter. But in general the UnsetValue is handed over, when the value of the property has not yet been given a value

Comment: @AndersH : Posted the converter part of the code. Please take a look at it

Comment: Please post all relevant parts of your code. Where exactly is QuantChartWindow set? How do the view model property declarations look like? What data binding errors do you observe in the Output Window in Visual Studio? My guess would be that the ElementName resolution fails.

Comment: Posted the other relavant parts of the code @Clemens

Comment: How about any data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio?

Comment: Nope!! Not that I see any...@Clemens

Answer (score 0):

Another approach avoiding binding by name might be the following:

```
<ContextMenuService.ContextMenu> <ContextMenu>
 <MenuItem IsCheckable="False" x:Name="MnuSendToFolder" Header="{Binding Path=SendToFolder, 
      Source={StaticResource LRWpf}}"   Command="{Binding SendToFolderCommand}" >
   <MenuItem.IsEnabled>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource VisibilityConverter}">
           <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=xmln_to_your_lib:QuantChartView}" Path="DataContext.IsSurveyModeOn" />
           <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=xmln_to_your_lib:QuantChartView}" Path="DataContext.CommonProgressVisibility" />
      </MultiBinding> 
    </MenuItem.IsEnabled>
 </MenuItem>
```

**Edit after getting few info on your scenario**

You shouldn't refer to `DataContext.<your_property>` because the ContextMenuService DataContext should be the same of `QuantChartWindow`.

So the code shoud be:

```
<ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>   <ContextMenu>
 <MenuItem IsCheckable="False" x:Name="MnuSendToFolder" Header="{Binding Path=SendToFolder, 
      Source={StaticResource LRWpf}}"   Command="{Binding SendToFolderCommand}" >
   <MenuItem.IsEnabled>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource VisibilityConverter}">
           <Binding Path="IsSurveyModeOn" />
           <Binding Path="CommonProgressVisibility" />
      </MultiBinding> 
    </MenuItem.IsEnabled>
 </MenuItem>
```

Please double-check also that your ViewModel implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface otherwise the Binding will not work properly.

Comment: can you please tell me what exactly u mean by xmln_to_your_lib ? Is the the namespace of my view model class QuantChartViewModel? I am a bit confused

Comment: @Anupriya yes it is

Comment: Nope! Still no luck :( I am new to Multibinding hence struggling with this bit of code. @trix

Comment: Please share the XAML code where you add the ContextMenuService

Comment: Updated in the question. Please take a look

Comment: I did this the first time I tried this. But wasn't working. Still am trying again.

Comment: Nope!! :( Still the same issue! @trix

Comment: @Anupriya Does the other Bindings work? for example the ChartType binded to SelectedChartType works correctly?

Comment: Yes it does, it goes to the getter section of the property SelectedChartType in the same view model class but for my properties(IsSurveyModeOn and CommonProgressVisibility), the code flow doesn't go to the get part of the property in view model. @trix

Answer (score 0):

You need more validation in your converter:

```
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
     if ((values != null) && 
         (values.Length == 2) &&
         (values[0] != null) &&
         (values[1] != null) &&
         (values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) &&
         (values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) &&
         (values[0] is bool) &&
         (values[1] is Visibility))
     {
        Visibility visvalue = (Visibility)values[1];
        bool isSurveyMode = (bool)values[0];
        if (visvalue == Visibility.Hidden || visvalue == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
           if (!isSurveyMode)
              return true;
        }
        else
           return false;
     }
     return false;
  }
```

It is because the converter can be called before your XAML is fully rendered. I have not checked if you have other issues in your XAML or the other code. So maybe this is not enough to solve your problem, but it is a part of it

Comment: Actually the other binding just above(ChartType binded to SelectedChartType) the one I am having issues with is working. But for my binding it doesn't go to the getter part of the bind property in ViewModel. Hence, I guess the XAML rendering should not be the issue.